# p:fileUpload dragDropSupport is not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 5.1. In my Page, I use `<p:fileUpload>` and set attribute `dragDropSupport="true"` for drag and drop file in `<p:fileUpload>`. It working in Mozilla and Chrome but not working in IE all versions and also Windows 7 Mozilla and Chrome also not working.

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadView.handleFileUpload}" 
              mode="advanced"
              dragDropSupport="true"
              update="messages"
              sizeLimit="100000"
              allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"/>
```